# How to solve this App Store warning screen issue?

Tags: ios, app-store

A user sent me a screenshot saying that my app no longer works for him when he is offline. It's an alert screen from the App Store indicating that "In order to access the App Store, you have to turn off airplane mode or enable WiFi".

This screen instantly appears over my app when he opens it. The app does use in-app purchases but it is a very old Objective-C based app.

[image]

I wasn't able to find any information on how I might eliminate this problem  and would appreciate any hints.

Comment: That is the App Store app. Does your app use SKProductViewController? Does it try and load the purchase receipt?  Have you tested your app with no network?

Comment: Yes it tries to load the purchase receipt. However in the past it never displayed a prompt like this when offline.

Comment: Something may have changed. It is not a good idea to always load the receipt for this sort of reason; It may prompt the user to authenticate to the App Store.  Interestingly the view is presented in a navigation view, so I would have thought that your app would be doing something to trigger the view; iOS will typically just show a system dialog, not actually unilaterally present something in your view hierarchy, because it doesn't necessarily know what your view hierarchy *is*.  It shouldn't be too hard to replicate this problem under the debugger.